# Error on adding a web service to project library as a service reference

Tags: c#, web-services

I am adding a webservice to a web project as a service reference. The error on adding which occurs on adding is

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved.

Before adding the webservice as a  service reference I tried adding it as web reference.On doing it there was no error but, i was not able to access a class through the web reference.
So I went for the option of service reference. 
I was able to add service reference to a web project and every thing works fine but I am unable to do the same in a class library.

Your help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your service in Solution Explorer and select View in browser.
you may have some errors in your service and in this way you can find out the errors.

Comment: thank you for the answer but, the webservice is not mine. This webservice is from a partner. And as i said this webservice works fine when i add it as a service reference to web project. Problem comes up when I add it as service reference to Class Library.